# how to make page re-render after localstorage change

Tags: reactjs

Please how can i make the useEffect make the page re-render on storage change? i'm using a radio button to change the value of the language, the code inside of the useEffect doesn't seem to work

```js
 const [lang, setLang] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang")));

  useEffect(() => {
    function checkUserData() {
      const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang"));

      if (item) {
        setLang(item);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
      checkUserData();
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", checkUserData);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    localStorage.setItem("lang", JSON.stringify({ [name]: value }));
    //setLang({ [name]: value });
    console.log(lang);
  };
```

Comment: The behaviour of the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) is subtle: it will only be triggered when another document context on the same domain (e.g. same site running in a different tab) makes a change. What you want is not really feasible. You should think about doing this the other way around - here is some useful starter code for a [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) hook.

Comment: in my case i should replace useLocalStorage("name", "Bob"); with useLocalStorage("lang", lang.value); ?

Answer (score 0):

Along with what lawrence-witt mentioned, [storage events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) don't fire on the same tab that the event got sent from, instead they are more aligned with having it so that two separate tabs can be kept in sync.

I modified your code to use a custom hook somewhat based off the one that lawrence-witt [linked](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/). The key difference being that I still included the storage events that would enable two different tabs to be synced up. Here's [the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/uselocalstorage-0r6cn3?file=/src/App.js), and the app is hosted at [this page](https://0r6cn3.csb.app/). If you open the page in two separate tabs, you can see how inputting values changes the other tab as well, which is one of the strongest parts of localStorage.

I included 2 sets of inputs, a textbox and some radios to show how this could work, especially working with react hook states and making sure to spread the object to avoid losing data accidentally.

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(
    // Use the function method for setting initial value to prevent unnecessary reads
    // Parse and then use initialValue in case the value stored in localStorage is "null" or "undefined"
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) ?? initialValue
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    // storage events occur when another tab is modifying localStorage.
    // Use it to keep two tabs in sync
    function fromStorage(ev) {
      // The key needs to match, otherwise we're using the wrong event.
      if (ev.key === key) {
        // Instead of grabbing the value again, the event has it!
        setStoredValue(JSON.parse(ev.newValue));
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("storage", fromStorage);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", fromStorage);
    };
    // Effect is dependent on the key
  }, [key]);
  /**
   * Custom setValue to mimic useState's, but include the localStorage setting
   */
  const setValue = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      // Use the storedValue's function setting to get the previous value, so that this callback can be tied to just the key.
      // To keep this callback referentially stable as long as the key isn't changed! Could also put the key in a ref, instead.
      setStoredValue((prevValue) => {
        // if the value is a function, run it against the previous value.
        const newValue = typeof value === "function" ? value(prevValue) : value;
        // Store the newValue
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
        return newValue;
      });
    },
    [key]
  );
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}

export default function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useLocalStorage("lang", { input: "", fruit: "pear" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLang((lang) => ({ ...lang, [name]: value }));
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: "0.5rem",
        alignItems: "flex-start"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ minHeight: "1em", lineHeight: "1em" }}>
        {JSON.stringify(lang)}
      </div>
      <input value={lang?.input ?? ""} name="input" onChange={handleChange} />
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <label>
          Apple
          <input
            name="fruit"
            type="radio"
            value="apple"
            checked={lang?.fruit === "apple" || false}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Pear
          <input
            name="fruit"
            type="radio"
            value="pear"
            checked={lang?.fruit === "pear" || false}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Plum
          <input
            name="fruit"
            type="radio"
            value="plum"
            checked={lang?.fruit === "plum" || false}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```